# node_module not getting loaded in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, node-modules, yarnpkg, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using the node_module [devicon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/devicon) in my rails 6 app. In development it's loading and working as intended but in production it's not there.

**application.js**

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")


// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)

require('jquery')
require('devicon')
```

---

**development**
[image: node_modules in development]

**production**
[image: node_modules in production]

---

**edit**
I fixed the problem by adding the css file of the package and the dependent fonts to my public folder without using webpack. I still don't know what the correct way of importing a npm package to your asset pipeline is. Webpack is extremly confusing for me.